# How to use this.store.find in Ember.Object in Ember Data 1.0 beta

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm now transitioning to Ember Data 1.0 beta from 0.13.

And I want to use find method in Em.Object like below.

```
App.SessionManager = Em.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user) {
      self.set('user', user);
    });;
  },
});
```

How can I achive this?

In [this document](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md), using App.inject is suggested. But this can be applied to Ember.Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `container.lookup("store:main")` and set that as a property on my object called `store`. Then in the object I could just use `this.store` like normal.

Comment: Just realized that `container` is available in my object because I'm setting it up in an initializer. So, not sure it will work the same for you.